# Trim video with ffmpeg is very slow

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanted to trim video with ffmpeg worker mp4 but this going very slow during the process the video here is my command for this

```
["-y", "-i", "video.mp4", "-ss", "00:00", "-to", "00:07", "output.mp4"]
```

the video is trimming but with very slow and not working with mobile device showing memory allocation error. please help me for this

Answer (score 5):

You can place `-ss` and `-to` in front of `-i` like below:

```
["-ss", "00:00:00", "-to", "00:00:07", "-i", "video.mp4", "output.mp4", "-y"]
```

It tells *FFmpeg* seek to the specified time before start decoding.

And by using `-c copy`, FFmpeg will copies from the input to the output file without re-encoding streams.

Also, using [trim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) filter may be helpful:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "trim=start=0:end=7" -af "atrim=start=0:end=7" output.mp4 -y
```

Comment: I have used your command but now this showing the error "Error opening input files: Invalid argument"

Comment: please tell what command will for trim with start and end time

Comment: I changed the positions and structure of times, check again plz...
  the final command: ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:07 -i video.mp4 -c copy output.mp4 -y (if you got the codec error just remove the "-c copy")

Comment: Did you run the FFmpeg command directly? Are you sure the video.mp4 has no problems? Did you validate the streams with ffprobe?

Comment: The answer updated with an example of trim command using -vf and -af